# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I updated the Sherlock action bar library to new version in my project. After compiling and running logcat shows NoClassDefFoundError.

I have checked the jar versions. I have added the jars in project libs folder. I also checked order and export tab in build path. I also tried clean and build. Still i am getting NoClassDefFoundError.

My LogCat is shown below

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo.TVBuddyMainActivity
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:54)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
 E/AndroidRuntime(9699):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

THE error line in splash screen

```
TVBuddyMainActivity.setSuccess(false);
```

i cant figure out the cause earlier working fine

My MAINFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"
    />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    >
     <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
         >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".TVBuddyMain"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomSearch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".PackageBuilderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        >           
    </activity>
      <service
        android:name="com.mobiotics.tvbuddy.data.service.Droid_service"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>    
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Check if TVBuddyMainActivity  is declared in your manifest

Comment: i have specified in manifest\

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: Also source of TVBuddyMainActivity can be usefull

Comment: @user1526671 please see my answer below

Comment: @user1526671 have you use my answer. are you using any jar file?

Comment: TVBuddyMainActivity isn't specified in manifest. RcdK was right.

Comment: yeah i have added JAR to classpath

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jar file. Do not add by "java Build path". Jar file should be in **libs** folder. if there is not libs folder create it and please put your jar file in **libs** folder.  Then Right click on jar file and do build path and add to build path.

thank u

Answer (score 1):

`com.mobiotics.tvbuddydemo.TVBuddyMainActivity` is not declared in android manifest file.

you have declared `android:name=".TVBuddyMain"` whic is not needed.

furthermore accessing static method inside an activity is not good idea.

```
TVBuddyMainActivity.setSuccess(false)
```

pass that false value through intent.